# How to make add a fade-in/fade-out animation based on ViewModel property value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, mvvm, triggers

I have a **ViewModel** which exposes the string property **PageToolBarVisible** which can be **true** or **false**:

```
private string _pageToolBarVisible;
public string PageToolBarVisible
{
    get
    {
        return _pageToolBarVisible;
    }

    set
    {
        _pageToolBarVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PageToolBarVisible");
    }
}
```

Then on my **View** I have this **DataTrigger** which **displays** or **hides** the toolbar accordingly:

```
<Style x:Key="PageToolBarStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PageToolBarVisible}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Border Style="{StaticResource PageToolBarStyle}"
    DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Padding="5 5 5 0" Background="#eee">
    <Grid Background="#eee">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

How do I now **add an** **animation** so that:

- when the ViewModel Property is changed from **true to false**, the **toolbar fades out**
- when the ViewModel Property is changed from **false to true**, the **toolbar fades in**

I assume I have to add something like this to my style, but I don't know how or where:

```
<BeginStoryboard>
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="PageToolBar"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
    From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:3"/>
</Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can put the BeginStoryboard inside your DataTrigger.EnterActions

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PageToolBarVisible}" Value="false">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="PageToolBar"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:3"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="PageToolBar"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                    From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:3"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: For those having problems with this method, it may be necessary to drop Storyboard.TargetName because it is not allowed in Style-triggers (anymore?). Here's the answer for that:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31929903/2582968