# How can I make a XAML Trigger call a XAML Style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers

This style correctly fades my toolbar in or out based on the changing of a ViewModel Property:

```
<Style x:Key="PageToolBarStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PageToolBarVisible}" Value="true">

            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            From="0.0" 
                            To="1.0" 
                            Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            From="1.0" 
                            To="0.0" 
                            Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>

        </DataTrigger>

        <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However, when the **application loads** the status of the toolbar (faded out or in) is **not in sync** with the value of the ViewModel property (true or false). So I want to **force this style to be executed** upon loading the window, what is the syntax to do this, here is pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>

           <!-- PSEUDO-CODE: -->
            <ExecuteTriggerStyle StyleToExecute="{StaticResource PageToolBarStyle}"/>

        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: Perhaps you're approaching this in the wrong way.  Instead of trying to force your style to execute (not what a style is for), you should look at trying to make sure that your PageToolBarVisible property is firing a propertyChanged event when the window is loaded.  That seems to make more sense to me.  You can handle this in the ViewModel's constructor.  That doesn't mean to say that what your trying to do is wrong ... just trying to help reframe the problem

Comment: Right, my ViewModel's constructor gets "false" out of the config file, assigns it to PageToolBarStyle, OnPropertyChanged("PageToolBarVisible") gets fired but the toolbar is visible in spite of that. And if the constructor sets it to "true", the when the application loads, the toolbar "fades in", which is only supposed to happen when the status changes, not when the application loads.  Hmmm, getting a little "subtle change animation" to work has more steps than I thought, I need to isolate this code more.

Comment: I posted a more isolated code example here showing the same issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092630/how-to-get-view-element-to-fade-in-out-based-on-value-of-viewmodel-property