# TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter, so how is it set?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, animation

I've spent this past week exploring WPF so it's still very new to me.  One of the things I'm working on is simple animations.  In this case a bouncing smiley face.

My plan of attack is:

1. Make a smiley face.  I've done this.
2. Work out the bouncing animation on a simple object.  I've done this.
3. Abstract that animation so it can be used in several places (the elements of the smiley face).  I'm stuck here.
4. Apply the abstracted animation style to all the elements of the smiley face.

After step #2 I had the the following working XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test Window" Height="350" Width="620">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Margin="0,180,0,0">
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="4" Fill="Aqua" />
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="12" Width="60" Height="30">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.45,0" EndPoint="0.5, 0.9">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="DarkMagenta" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="Transparent" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="33" Canvas.Top="35" Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="White" />
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="43" Width="6" Height="5" Fill="Black" />
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="68" Canvas.Top="35" Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="White" />
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="43" Width="6" Height="5" Fill="Black" />
            <Path Name="mouth" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="4" Data="M 35,75 Q 55,90 80,75 " />
        </Canvas>
        <Grid Margin="100,5,0,0" Width="75" Height="300">
            <Canvas>
                <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40" x:Name="theBall" Canvas.Left="16">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.75,0.25">
                            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.0" />
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="aniSquash"/>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="aniBounce"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <Ellipse.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard SpeedRatio="2.0">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:4.5" Storyboard.TargetName="aniBounce" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="120" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="260" KeyTime="0:0:2.2" KeySpline="0, 0, 0.5, 0"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="260" KeyTime="0:0:2.25"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="120" KeyTime="0:0:4.5" KeySpline="0, 0, 0, 0.5"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:4.5" Storyboard.TargetName="aniSquash" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1.3" KeyTime="0:0:2.25"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.5"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:4.5" Storyboard.TargetName="aniSquash" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.7" KeyTime="0:0:2.25"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.5"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Ellipse.Triggers>
                </Ellipse>
                <Rectangle Height="5" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="285" Width="55" Fill="Black"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

While altering the above, working, XAML for step #3 I introduced an error I don't really understand.  Here is the altered XAML that doesn't work:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test Window" Height="350" Width="620">
    <Window.Resources>
        <TransformGroup x:Key="aniBounceAndSquash">
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="aniSquash"/>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="aniBounce"/>
        </TransformGroup>
        <Style x:Key="styleBounceAndSquash" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform" Value="{StaticResource aniBounceAndSquash}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard SpeedRatio="2.0">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:4.5" Storyboard.TargetName="aniBounce" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="120" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="260" KeyTime="0:0:2.2" KeySpline="0, 0, 0.5, 0"/>
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="260" KeyTime="0:0:2.25"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="120" KeyTime="0:0:4.5" KeySpline="0, 0, 0, 0.5"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:4.5" Storyboard.TargetName="aniSquash" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2"/>
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1.3" KeyTime="0:0:2.25"/>
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.5"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:4.5" Storyboard.TargetName="aniSquash" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2"/>
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.7" KeyTime="0:0:2.25"/>
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.5"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Margin="0,180,0,0">
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="4" Fill="Aqua" />
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="12" Width="60" Height="30">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.45,0" EndPoint="0.5, 0.9">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="DarkMagenta" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="Transparent" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="33" Canvas.Top="35" Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="White" />
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="43" Width="6" Height="5" Fill="Black" />
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="68" Canvas.Top="35" Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="White" />
            <Ellipse Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="43" Width="6" Height="5" Fill="Black" />
            <Path Name="mouth" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="4" Data="M 35,75 Q 55,90 80,75 " />
        </Canvas>
        <Grid Margin="100,5,0,0" Width="75" Height="300">
            <Canvas>
                <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40" x:Name="theBall" Canvas.Left="16" Style="{StaticResource styleBounceAndSquash}">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.75,0.25">
                            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.0" />
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <Rectangle Height="5" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="285" Width="55" Fill="Black"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The error "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter. Line 20 Position 79."

If I can't set it in the style how do I set it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well it turns out that you can't set `Storyboard.TargetName` in a `Style.Setter` because it's a style and is abstracted.  Hence a reference via name is not allowed as "there is no spoon".  So I dropped `Storyboard.TargetName` and looked for another way.

I did find that in `Storyboard.TargetProperty` you can use the object structure, sort of like walking the DOM, to reference the object you want. In that way you bypass the need for `Storyboard.TargetName`.  It took longer to work out referencing the object by structure because I was using a `TransformGroup` and MS docs are not the most friendly of docs.  Finally, I got it and here it is for anyone else that has the same problem.

```
<Style x:Key="buttonSmiley" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnVisibleStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:2.75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.Y)" >
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="75" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="25" KeyTime="0:0:0.75" KeySpline="0, 0, 0.5, 0"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="-25" KeyTime="0:0:1.2"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="200" KeyTime="0:0:2.25" KeySpline="0, 0, 0, 0.5"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="175" KeyTime="0:0:2.4" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="150" KeyTime="0:0:2.75" KeySpline="0, 0, 0, 0.5"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:5.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" >
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.01" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:1.25"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.05"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1.15" KeyTime="0:0:2.15"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.4"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.75"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:5.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" >
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.01" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:1.25"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.05"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.75" KeyTime="0:0:2.2"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.4"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.75"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OnLoadStoryboard_BeginStoryboard"/>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnVisibleStoryboard_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnVisibleStoryboard}"/>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OnVisibleStoryboard_BeginStoryboard"/>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnLoadStoryboard_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnVisibleStoryboard}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas Margin="-35,-35,0,0">
                    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="50" Height="50" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#FFD8CF15" />
                    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="18" Canvas.Top="12" Width="33" Height="15">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.45,0" EndPoint="0.5, 0.9">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="DarkMagenta" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="Transparent" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="17" Canvas.Top="25" Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="White" />
                    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="28" Width="3" Height="3" Fill="Black" />
                    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="34" Canvas.Top="25" Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="White" />
                    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="37" Canvas.Top="28" Width="3" Height="3" Fill="Black" />
                    <Path Name="mouth" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M 20,43 Q 27,53 40,44" />
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransformGroup>
                <TranslateTransform />
                <ScaleTransform />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Of course I would have given up on the style altogether if `Button.Triggers` would have allowed normal triggers and not JUST event triggers in the collection, thank you MS for making life painful, er um I mean fun.  Because I needed both I had to work this out.

Comment: For those looking into what the DOM-walking feature is called, I found this doc on "PropertyPath XAML Syntax", which also describes caveats for animation targets. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax

Comment: This is amazing!

Comment: Great answer, explains _why_ WPF doesn't like it!

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue because I was building a custom resource (a button).

This was my problem, and its solution:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                ...
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    ==> should have put triggers here <==
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        ==> not here <==
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of your animation applied to a `Button`. Its probably not quite the answer you're looking for as it does not have reusable resources. I have just moved the `TransformGroup`, `Trigger` and `Storyboard` into the control. I will take another look...

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource styleBounceAndSquash}">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="aniSquash"/>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="aniBounce"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard SpeedRatio="2.0">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:4.5" Storyboard.TargetName="aniBounce" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="120" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="260" KeyTime="0:0:2.2" KeySpline="0, 0, 0.5, 0"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="260" KeyTime="0:0:2.25"/>
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame Value="120" KeyTime="0:0:4.5" KeySpline="0, 0, 0, 0.5"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:4.5" Storyboard.TargetName="aniSquash" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1.3" KeyTime="0:0:2.25"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.5"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:4.5" Storyboard.TargetName="aniSquash" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.7" KeyTime="0:0:2.25"/>
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.5"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the button example.  That got me thinking about applying the animation to a parent object rather than all the individual objects.  That was a better course of action.